# error message concerning deprecation

Tags: python, error-handling, deprecated

I ran some python code and got this error message:

C:\Python26\lib\sets.py:85: DeprecationWarning: functions overriding warnings.showwarning() must support the 'line' argument
  stacklevel=2)

I am not sure if this is some warning that I can just ignore or if this is serious? Any input will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`? Could you show us the code that's producing the warning?

Answer (score 2):

No worries.  The warning is about something in the standard library that was already fixed in Python 2.7.  You can safely ignore it :-)

The *sets.py* is part of the standard library.  Line 85 is just a warning that the sets module is deprecated in favor of the *set()* builtin method but that won't disappear until Python3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It *will* get serious. See [PEP 4](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0004/) for the details. But `DeprecationWarning`s tell you that some functionality is about to change in the next Python version.

Comment: Will this be an issue if I just use python 2.0 instead of the current version?

Comment: That might be good advice for warnings in general, but the core devs take care of the code in the standard library which in generating warnings.  Also, the deprecation in question doesn't take place until the 3.x series.  So, the OP can continue to safely use sets.py in Py2.x if he/she so desires.  That being said, the code would likely run faster if the OP migrates to the using the set() builtin instead of sets.py, but it isn't mandatory in Py2.x.